# Why does application was called from service can not show when logon by remote desktop

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-services

I write a Windows service, It calls exe (pass UAC). So when I restart windows, service will run and call exe running even windows still not log on. Then I logon the windows, exe's UI will show up in the desktop. So the problem is: when I log on in windows by my PC (sessionID of my exe and winlogon.exe is the same), everything runs normal, no problem happen, but when I restart windows - not logon yet - using remote desktop to logon - no UI show(sessionID of my exe and remote desktop's winlogon.exe is the same, but now there are 2 winlogon.exe are running). So I dont't know why this happen. Please tell me if you have the explain. thank you

Edit1: I found that if we use remote desktop, and turn on any application, the application's session is not the same with remote desktop's winlogon.exe session).

Comment: I don't now the answer, but I really wonder why you want to do this. This opens a huge security hole.

Comment: I want to run an application before windows user logon

Comment: But why? You should put everything that needs to run before logon into the service. Then start the UI during logon (via one of the many Autostart options avaiable) and communicate with the service.

Comment: If I write my winform.exe as a service, It takes me a lot of time, So I did an easier way

Comment: It might be easier. But don't do it. Having an UI with the privileges of a service will allow an attacker to quite easily take over the system.

Comment: Please study what is session isolation. What you observed is pretty normal.